# Contextmenu showmodal

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, contextmenu

As i see contextmenu has only `Show()`. But not `ShowModal()`.

What i need is to be sure user clicked on any item in the menu. User must click on any of it.

I can look on Closing event with cancel property. But even when i set cancel to true - winforms allows to select another treeview's node (contextmenu for tree node).

So how fully to make context menu modal ?

For now i have to write like this

```
void contextMenuTreeView_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
            return;

        if (treeView.SelectedNode != null && treeView.SelectedNode.Tag != null)
        {
            if (ChangeCustomerEventHandler != null)
                ChangeCustomerEventHandler(this, new CustomerTreeNodeEventArgs((Guid)treeView.SelectedNode.Tag));
        }
        else
        {
            if (NewCustomerEventHandler != null)
                NewCustomerEventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show standard menus in a modal way as you hope to do. That's just not how menus work.

If you want a modal selection then show a modal dialog. Place the possible options in, for instance, a radio group, and only allow the modal dialog to close when the user has made a selection that satisfies you.